# no lwjgl in java.library.path in playN hello sample

Tags: lwjgl, playn

I'm having an error trying to run java playN project. The other ons seems to be fine. The error is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path.

There is dependencied library lwjgl 2.83 in the project. Whatis wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you have the java dependency, you don't have the native library.

You'll need to download lwjgl from http://www.lwjgl.org/, unpack and set up according to http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Getting_started

TL;DR: Once you have your plattform's libraries extracted you need to point Java there using the following as VM Parameters:

```
-Djava.library.path=[Path/To/Libs]
```

I think if you run it with maven instead, it should work out of the box (maybe)

/Edit: or follow this instruction:
[How to fix java.lang...](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/playn/E2t7gNh4ab0)
it doesn't depend on your own downloaded libraries but fetches them using maven.

Answer (score -2):

to solve the problems when first using Java Media Frameworks, JMF 2.11e,
configure environmental variables for:
JAVA_HOME=
JMF_HONE=
also you need a policy file from policy tool and then
add -Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy
for additional librarires
add -Djava.library.path=
also install a 32-bit verison of jdk and jre I use 8 personally.
in Netbeans, if you are using it, select JDK 8 and it should work.
then try to compile JMStudio and if it will boot even with errors, 
it should enable preferences, detect capture devices and the camera light
will do its blinking, then it comes up and you can go to file|capture at that
point and it will record you and let you see yourself via a visual component on the screen.

Best way to learn JMF is to reverse engineer JMStudio and architect/engineer your
own solution!
Enjoy.