# In PlayN, how can I upgrade to PlayN version 1.3.1 without getting "no lwjgl in java.library.path" error?

Tags: eclipse, maven, lwjgl, playn

#### Update

The reason I couldn't update properly was I didn't have game's jar file properly installed. That was fixed by first running this on the command line:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.mygame -DartifactId=mygame-core -Dversion=0.9-beta -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/klenwell/projects/mygame/playn/mygame/java/target/mygame-java-0.9-beta.jar
```

Then, in Eclipse, I right-clicked java folder > Maven > Test. This updated all my dependencies including lwjgl.

Otherwise, see [thomasbroad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265797/1093087).

#### Original Question

I've consulted the following authorities on this topic and applied their various recommendations:

- http://lwjgl.org/installation.php
- http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Maven
- http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065814/1093087
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/playn/E2t7gNh4ab0
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/playn/3D4JZ1Dbm-E/HmPHofS2fqgJ

Part of the problem is I'm not sure whether I should be following the Maven instructions or the Eclipse instructions. I've tried both and everything in between.

I'm working in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on Eclipse using Maven. Everything was working fine until I changed the PlayN version in my POM file from 1.2 to 1.3.1 and introduced the lwjgl dependency.

**What I would have expected to have worked:**

1) Download lwjgl (latest version 2.8.4) and test per lwjgl.org instructions (this was successful)

2) Update the appropriate POM files

2A) Add lwjgl.version as a property to mygame/pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <playn.version>1.3.1</playn.version>
    <lwjgl.version>2.8.4</lwjgl.version>
  </properties>
```

2B) Add lwjgl as a dependency to mygame/mygame-java/pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>${lwjgl.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

3) Right-click mygame-java project in Eclipse > Run As > Run Configurations > Arguments and add either `-Djava.library.path=target/natives` or `-Djava.library.path=/absolute/path/to/my/lwjgl/lib` to VM arguments. (I've tried both variations.)

I can see the dependencies listed under my java project folder in Eclipse. And when I follow the lwjgl.org guide for Eclipse, I can see the jar listed under the java project folder. But I still get the error.

After two hours of hair-wrenching frustration, I hope somebody can either point out my fatal oversight or provide explicit instructions that will help me get back to work. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up reverting to PlayN v1.2 for now. Waiting for this problem to be resolved before trying again to upgrade to v1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded my project from 1.2 to 1.3 a while ago. I only updated my `pom.xml` files to refer to the new version of PlayN . I did not manually install `lwjgl` and neither did I add the `lwjgl` dependency as that one is implicitly pulled in by PlayN

**Manually apply the diffs** found [here](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/detail?r=dbf7ff37d3ba0f87c912143f9f01ee4012b35a80#) to your project, to your poms.

The key part being the piece in the java pom that tells Maven to unpack native dependencies. This part was actually added in the previous diff, so you may want to look [there](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/detail?r=21ad9a3babc277ddc13fd91903ef115f7d3e4ccc) as well.

Now your IDE will most likely tell you that your project is not up-to-date with your poms, **update your project**, this should pull in the `lwjgl` dependency and set it up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I applied the changes as you suggested. You can see the changeset here: http://klenwell.com/is/Pastebin20120630. I then clicked Maven > Update Dependencies... on the java project directory in Eclipse. I still get the `no lwjgl in java.library.path` error when I try to run the application.

Comment: One thing that puzzles me how is Eclipse or Maven supposed to figure out where to find lwjgl within the changes you linked to if you don't manually install it? Maven remains complete voodoo to me.

Comment: Maven knows about the `lwjgl` dependency because it is specified in the playn list of dependencies. As soon as you specified the `PlayN 1.3.1` version, Maven should start pulling in `lwjgl`.

Comment: Finally got it. Turns out that the problem was I didn't have the path to my main game class jar properly configured in Maven and I guess that was blocking the updates. Fixing that enabled it to build properly. Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should add the `-Djava.library.path` arguments to the VM Arguments, not to the Program Arguments in your runtime configuration.

The other -using maven- option is described on the [Getting Started page](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Running_the_imported_samples), it worth noting, that the default embedded Maven is buggy for development, you should download and use at least Maven 3.0.3 as it is mentioned on the page (but I guess you already do this).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had the library path set under VM arguments (I was just tracking how you get there in Eclipse) and I'm on Maven 3.0.3. But looking again at Getting Started page and running maven through command line led me to the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just started a new project fresh with PlayN 1.4 and encountered this issue again in Eclipse. Resolved it as follows:

Right click mygame-java > Run As > Run Configurations...

Then added the following to VM Arguments under Arguments tab:

```
-Djava.library.path=target/natives
```

Then successfully ran as application.

At one point, I also ran the `mvn install:install-file...` command mentioned in question but I'm not sure whether that was necessary or not.